# Should I use inheritance or composition?

Tags: perl, inheritance, oop, composition

I would like to keep this one short. I build a HouseA that has two rooms, say `BedRoom` and `StudyRoom`, both deriving from a base class called `Room`.
`BedRoom` and `StudyRoom` have a same parent called `House`. Also, any room in a house can access any other rooms only through the parent. If `BedRoom` has to access any attribute of `StudyRoom`, it has to go only via `House` (i.e. parent) and vice-versa.

```
HouseA ISA House
HouseA HAS BedRoom and StudyRoom.
BedRoom ISA Room
StudyRoom ISA Room
```

Now the Problem: Let's say, I build another home (say `HouseB`), which is a exactly the same as the above, but with one change. I don't want two separate rooms (i.e. `BedRoom` and `StudyRoom`), but instead a single room (`MasterRoom`) which has both these facilities. 
For the sake of code reusability, I could think of the following design options:

```
Option-1:
HouseB ISA House
HouseB HAS MasterRoom
MasterRoom ISA Room
```

Here I lose the ability to reuse the attributes of `BedRoom` and `StudyRoom` that I created for `HouseA`. Note that most of the attributes of `BedRoom` and `StudyRoom` need to be reimplemented in `MasterRoom` anyway, thereby resulting in code duplication.

```
Option-2:
HouseB ISA House
HouseB HAS MasterRoom
MasterRoom ISA Room
MasterRoom HAS LogicalBedroom
MasterRoom HAS LogicalStudyRoom
LogicalBedroom ISA BedRoom
LogicalStudyRoom ISA StudyRoom
```

This way, I use composition so that I could reuse most of my code (I have several thousand lines of code that I could reuse), but the problem is that `BedRoom` is a concrete class and `logicalBedRoom` may find certain attributes not suitable and may be forced to override  methods so that they do nothing.  For example, `Bedroom->noOfSides() = 4` and `logicalBedRoom->noOfSides() = ??`. Is this a good use of inheritance?

My actual design is for a complex chip that combines the functionality of two individual chips (I used House (motherboard) and Room (chip) analogy). I code in Object Oriented Perl and I would really appreciate any alternate design suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why not use roles to achieve this:

```
House A has a Bedroom
Bedroom does SleepingArea
House has a Studyroom
Studyroom does ComfyArea

House B has a MasterRoom
MasterRoom does SleepingArea and ComfyArea
```

The easiest way to get [roles](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose::Manual::Roles) is to use [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose).

Comment: Is Role same as Mixin in Ruby?

Comment: @ragu.pattabi, roles are similar to mixins. The main difference is that roles have some controls on when they can be applied--roles can require that certain methods are available in a consuming class.  There are other differences, too.  Perl usage of the term role maps to 'traits' in the larger world of OO research. In Perl/Moose a trait is a role applied to a method using the meta-object protocol, which is beyond the scope of this reply. I raise the point so that I can avoid the appearance of non-sequitor as I direct you to a resource on traits in general: http://scg.unibe.ch/research/traits/

Comment: That means roles provide mechanism like template method pattern without the baggage of inheritance. That's pretty interesting.

Comment: @ragu.pattabi, yes.  The papers on the traits are worth a read.  They go into depth on the advantages of traits vs inheritance and mixin code reuse.   Roles/traits are amazing, to find out exactly why read the papers, find an implementation, and try them out.